# Error Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-router-dom

Tengo un proyecto principal "react-app" y he creado un proyecto que contiene los componentes "react-app-components".

En el proyecto "react-app-components" utilizo `Route` del `react-router-dom` y luego lo importo desde el "react-app" a través del `npm link` y al ejecutar `npm start` me sale el error:

> `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>`

Pero si publico el componentes en el npm y lo instalo con "npm install" funciona correctamente, es decir solo sale error cuando utilizo el `npm link` al trabajar en local.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de React, esto suele pasar por tener el React duplicado (more than one copy of React) https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Al parecer al utilizar el `npm link` la aplicación intenta utilizar el react de los proyectos "react-app" y del "react-app-components" y por eso al publicarlo en el `repositorio npm` ya no sale el error.

Para solucionarlo quité las dependencias del `react`, `react-router-dom` del `package.json` y volví a ejecutar `npm install` para que elimine las carpetas del node_modules.

**package.json**

Antes:

```
    
{
  //...
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Después:

```
    
{
  //...
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Solo dejo los "@types" para trabajar con typescript